# Taking more time to fetch records using DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net) for Paginating my result. Here is the code i am using

```
$('#datatable_paging').dataTable(
                {
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "iDisplayLength":15,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": false
                    }
                );
```

Now, it's working fine but the problem is it's taking time to load the result, because i am  fetching all the records without `LIMIT`(Example: 2000). I did search in the internet and i found this links.

1. [DataTables server-side processing example for PHP](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)
2. [DataTables server-side processing example for Code-Igniter](https://github.com/blake-nouribekian/codeigniter-datatables)

Before process the server side coding i want to make sure that is there any settings to `LIMIT` my query with the code which i have posted above?

Comment: although datatable is good but what if you have thousands of records it will take a lot of execution time i won't recommend it

Comment: i had 3k rows (and 10 cols) and it loads < 2 sec

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at server side processing to load the records.
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

This way you only need return enough records to display one page and each time you click next it will do a quick ajax request to get the next lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a LIMIT in the server side database query, it will reduce the time required to transfer data from database to PHP and then form php to js.
Please let me know if there is any constrain which can hinder the use of LIMIT clause.

Comment: The code i have posted above is client side process. If we put the limit, how about the remaining records?

Comment: Sorry ..!!Mistake "You can put a LIMIT in the query itself" -> put limit in database query in the server side script. Will it work ?